# BufferedReader reader.readLine() returns null

Tags: java, android, json, bufferedreader

I have jsonparser class to read the page line by line and convert it to json.But in my jsonparser class when i try to read the page line by line reader.readLine() returns null.

This is my JsonParser.java

```
final String TAG = "JsonParser.java";
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
 public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    // make HTTP request
    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.contains(";"))
            {
            line=line.replace(";", "");
            }
            if(line.contains("info = "))
            {
                line.replace("info = ","");
            }
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        Log.e(TAG, "Control5");

            json=sb.toString();

    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException occurred!!");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result " + e.toString());

    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        Log.e(TAG,json);
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

And i use this class in my MainActivity.java in Asynctask like this.

```
String videoid="mAQln4dgR24";
    long currenttime=System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

    yourJsonStringUrl="http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/itemInfo/?video_id="+videoid+"&ac=www&t=grp&r="+currenttime;
    /*
    //if you want to see the page use browserintent.
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(yourJsonStringUrl));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
    */

JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
        // get json string from url
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourJsonStringUrl);
```

The link "jsonstringurl" will be generated when program runs.
And it broke about little time.If you want to see the page use browser intent.

Comment: @GiruBhai Read the question. No exception is mentioned. He states there is an unexpected null return value from readLine().

Comment: @OmerFaruk The only problem here is that there is no output to read, so you immediately get a null. It seems to me you should be doing GET, not POST.

Comment: @EJP I tried your solution but it didnt work.Still Program cannot enter the while loop.

Comment: So there is still no data to read. The server didn't send anything.